# How can I install Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, startup-disk-creator

I tried to install Startup Disk Creator using:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

But it didn't appear in the dash.

What should I do?

Comment: I think the Startup Disk Creator is already installed (unless you have removed it). Have you tried to type the letters 'usb-c' (without quotes) in the dash?

Comment: [usb-c]  - didn't find the comand  @sudodus

Comment: I assume that you are running standard Ubuntu with the Unity desktop. *Do you know how to use the dash?* -- Click on the Ubuntu icon in the top left corner of the screen. After that type the letters of the program name and you should see them (the letters). And you should also see the selected items change. The more letters you type, the more specific selection, and after a few letters (and maybe some other characters (in this case the minus sign, '-') only one icon is left.

Comment: Alternative from the terminal window: type `usb-creator-gtk` and press the Enter key.

Comment: Note I've also seen this missing in the ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Click on the Ubuntu icon in the top left corner of the screen. After that type the letters of the program name and you should see them (the letters). And you should also see the selected items change. The more letters you type, the more specific selection, and after a few letters (and maybe some other characters (in this case the minus sign, '-') only one icon is left."
/sudodus  - *in the comments*

Additonally you may pick (with the mouse) a visible icon and drag it into the Launcher, and it will sit there until you remove it.

Comment: `Click on the Ubuntu icon ` for me the Startup Disk Creator is not accessible by the task manager. What can I do?

Comment: Hold left "Super" key (Win key), hit A. Then type "startup d" ... and the icon will appear. Or use the Ubuntu icon as described above, and type the same "startup d" -> same effect.

Answer (score 91):

If you cannot find it just install it running in terminal those commands (first two are optional, to update the repos, and upgrade what should be upgraded, but if you just want to make pendrive with installer, just skip to the third line.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

For me it worked, Ubuntu tutorials and forums stated that it is build in, from 18.04, but it's not if you have other flavor than "vanilla" Ubuntu, for example Budgie.

Then you may also start this from terminal:

```
usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: Someone even put this answer into a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator) =3

Comment: Thank you for this answer... everybody saying "go to your applications! it's listed there!" It wasn't, and it wasn't listed under the Applications and Software either.

Answer (score 1):

if it doesn't appear in the dash then go to your package manager and search for startup, there you will find a package named "startup disk creator", right click on it and select mark for installation and then apply changes, after that close the package manager then search for startup disk creator, you will find it.